# Can't delete file even though permissions allow

Tags: permissions, osx, nfs

I NFS export a folder from MacOS 10.12 and mount it on Centos 6.

The UID and GID between the machines is the same, but from the Linux box I cannot delete files unless the directory has "write everyone" permissions set.

Why not?

The files can be deleted after changing permissions of the enclosing folder to 777

**On Mac Side**

```
mac$ ls -lnd
drwxrwxr-x  143 501  501  4862 28 Mar 09:21 ./

mac$ ls -ln *debug*
lrwxrwxrwx  1 501  501    15 22 Mar 16:45 libdvdebug.so@ -> libdvdebug.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx  1 501  501    20 22 Mar 16:45 libdvdebug.so.6@ -> libdvdebug.so.6.0-34
-rwxrwxr-x  1 501  501  7042 22 Mar 16:45 libdvdebug.so.6.0-34*

mac$ id
uid=501(danny) gid=501(djw) groups=501(djw),104(com.apple.access_ssh-disabled),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),502(access_bpf),12(everyone),
20(staff),61(localaccounts),66(_uucp),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),506(finance),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),
395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing)

$ grep 168.2 /etc/exports
/Work/Software_Devel -alldirs -maproot=danny  -network 192.168.2.0   -mask 255.255.255.0
```

**On Linux Side**

```
linux$ ls -ln *debug*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 501 501   15 Mar 22 16:45 libdvdebug.so -> libdvdebug.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx 1 501 501   20 Mar 22 16:45 libdvdebug.so.6 -> libdvdebug.so.6.0-34
-rwxrwxr-x 1 501 501 7042 Mar 22 16:45 libdvdebug.so.6.0-34

linux$ id
uid=501(tqdevel) gid=501(tqdevel) groups=501(tqdevel)

linux$ ls -ldn .
drwxrwxr-x 143 501 501 4862 Mar 28 09:21 .

linux$ mount
192.168.2.10:/Work/Software_Devel on /mnt/swdevel type nfs 
(rw,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr,addr=192.168.2.10)

# showmount -e 192.168.2.10
Export list for 192.168.2.10:
/Work/Video Project  192.168.245.0
/Work/Software_Devel 10.0.0.0,10.128.112.0,10.128.113.0,172.16.16.0,192.168.135.224,
192.168.15.0,192.168.2.0,192.168.245.0,192.168.87.0,192.168.9.0
```

Comment: Please add the output of the `exports`file on the mac and the output of `showmount -e 192.168.2.10` on the linux machine to your question.

Comment: updated as requested

Comment: Acl's work differently on Macs and Linux's. The directory may have some mac-acls set that allow child Deletion even when it isn't world-writtable. Try removing acls set on that directory.

Comment: You could remove them if they are present via `chmod -a "everyone allow delete_child" directory`  Replacing `directory` with the path to the directory.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't indicated but try to reset the ACL permissions.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/187848)

Comment: @JeffSchaller This is an answer and it may well be correct. OSX does have a delete ACL.

Comment: Are there specific steps to "try to reset the ACL permissions"?

Comment: @Gilles: I agree with you that this is an answer, and I agree with Jeff that is probably wrong.  Does mac OS’s `ls -l` show an eleventh mode character (after `drwxrwxr-x`) when an ACL is present?

Comment: There are no ACLs.  ie, ls -le or ls -l@ shows nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$ ls -l
$ whoami
$ groups
```

Then check if the files belong to you or your group.

Enjoy.